24.04 - Thunderbolt 4 hub partially recognized - Intermittent connection
Problem
I connect a Thunderbolt 4 hub to my laptop. I plug a USB mouse to it. The mouse works in a cycle, 5s on, 5s off.
Platform
Computer: Dell XPS 13 9340
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Hub: https://en.j5create.com/products/jcd403
Kernel: The latest I could find, 6.8.0-45
Investigation

It seems to work flawlessly in BIOS and Windows 11.

I tried Fedora 40, it worked in the live OS, the hub was actually displayed in the Thundbolt page. Once installed it behaved the same way as in Ubuntu.
I tried to install PopOS but it failed even launching live due to the intermittent connection.

The hub "worked" the first time on Ubuntu after install. It was not disconnecting but it did NOT appear on the thunderbolt page. If I disconnected and then reconnected it, it failed and I needed to reboot the PC. And as soon as I clicked on the radio button "Authorize only USB and display port", the problem started.

I looked online for information and in the BIOS I did not find any interesting option (secure, legacy, you name it).

I tried the Archlinux udev solution and it did not work. (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Thunderbolt).

The /bus/thunderbolt/domain shows 'user' for the security config.

Dmesg shows "Retimer disconnected" "new retimer found" for each connection cycle. But I did not find any details on why the retimer disconnected.

When the dock "works" for 5s I can see a 0-0:1.1 new file in the /sys/bus/thunderbolt folder. Probably the connection is kind of working. I can also see the chips in the hub via lsusb. So it detects it to some extent but then just cuts the connection.


I am running out of ideas. It looks to me like a Linux Thunderbolt 4 / USB 4 support issue.
Do you have any idea of what is going on ?
Is there any terminal command I could enter to get more details, logging on what is going on (I am a linux beginner btw) ?
Where could I report the problem to see if it is actually a kernel support bug ?

Are you me? Same issue, same laptop. I've been struggling with this for months now...
I *think* my problem is Thunderbolt
I wish I had an answer for you.
I've tried boltctl and tbtools, updated the bios to v1.8.0 and enabled all Thunderbolt things, udev rules, etc.
I've tried Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04, and 24.04. No luck... But! Windows 11 works as expected.
If you figure it out, let me know.
Edit: I found success by downgrading my kernel to linux-image-6.5.0-1020-oem. Doing a full shutdown and then booting while the hub was plugged in allowed me to authorize and enroll it as a Thunderbolt 4 hub. I still cannot do any hotplugging, though. Very annoying.

Lol welcome to the club. I contacted the manufacturer of the hub and they said they do not support Linux, only windows and MacOS so we are on our own.
It has to be a bug in the kernel related to Thunderbolt 4.
I disabled thunderbolt in the BIOS and the hub worked perfectly well (at least for the USB4, I didn't check the Ethernet or the HDMI 2.1)
As soon as I reenable the TB4 in bios problems arise.
I will try to learn driver programming and debug that xD. See you in a few years.
Unless a new kernel fixes it. But 24.10 seems to also be buggy (6.11 kernel)

Second class Thunderbolt citizens :( My hub works fine when I use a regular 480M USB-C cable.  I have four Thunderbolt 4 and USB4 cables, and all of them cause the problem. It's probably a kernel issue, and I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting it.
